# How to change the color of a grid column in MVVM?

Tags: css, html, mvvm, data-binding, kendo-ui

How to change the color of a grid column in MVVM?
i would like something like this:

first column: green

second column: yellow

```
<div data-role="grid"
             data-toolbar="DOC"
             data-columns="[
                             { 'field': 'doc1'},
                             { 'field': 'doc2' }
                          ]"
             data-bind="source: sourceList"></div>
```

i would like to get something like this image:[image]

Comment: Is it always these two colors? Hard-coded green for the first column and yellow for the second?

Comment: Yes
Just for the header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following style to your CSS or page:

```
#grid th:nth-child(1) {
  background: green;
}

#grid th:nth-child(2) {
  background: yellow;
}
```

You'll need to set the selectors according to your setup.